# Open a text file with a Firebase Storage

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-storage

Here I need to open for reading the text, at first I want to save it on the personal computer, then open for reading but in the saved file its full way in Firebase Storage.
What's the problem, please help?

```
class FirebaseStorageHelper
    {
        FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = new FirebaseStorage("***************.appspot.com");

        public async Task<string> UploadFile(Stream fileStream, string fileName)
        {
            var imageUrl = await firebaseStorage
                .Child("Folder")
                .Child(fileName)
                .PutAsync(fileStream);
            return imageUrl;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetFile(string fileName)
        {
            return await firebaseStorage
                .Child("Folder")
                .Child(fileName)
                .GetDownloadUrlAsync();
        }
        public async Task DeleteFile(string fileName)
        {
            await firebaseStorage
                 .Child("Folder")
                 .Child(fileName)
                 .DeleteAsync();

        }
    }

public async void dowload(){
            FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"D:\Yourfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs1);
            
            string path = await firebaseStorageHelper.GetFile("file1.txt");
            if (path != null)
            {
                writer.Write(await firebaseStorageHelper.GetFile("file1.txt"));
                writer.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Path " + path);
                Path = path;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How are you using Firebase with C#? It's not officially in the docs. Are you using some kind of client? If yes, which? Also, what is the issue you're having?

Comment: I need to open for reading the text, at first I want to save it on the personal computer, then open for reading but in the saved file its full way in Firebase Storage.

Comment: Sure, I get that. But what is the problem that is stopping you from doing that?